# C++ program keeps beeping and crashes even after exit(0)

Tags: c++, exit

I am trying to make a program that tries to match a "password" introduced by the user by changing one character at a time, starting with a 1 character long word up to a 20 characters long one.
This program is just meant as a practice for loops, etc.
I am fully aware that I can simply write "cout << password;" but that's not fun ;)
The program is meant to stop after it finds the password using "exit(0);".

So this weird thing keeps happening to me that if the password is more than one character long (normally I type two characters, because it takes a lot of time for the thing to work if the password is very long) the program keeps beeping even after matching the password and eventually crashes.
Interestingly enough, if the word is just one character long, it stops beeping after matching the password and it doesn't crash.

I have read that the beeping might be a thing of printing ASCII charcters or something like that. That I get it, but why does it keep beeping AFTER the program has found the password and stopped? Is it still processing ASCII characters in the background or something?

Here's the code (I'm sorry if it's a bit chaotic but you can get the idea of what it does from my explanation, I hope):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

string get_password()
{
    //Asks for a password between 1 and 20 characters, both included.
    string password;
    do
    {
        cout << "Type a password: ";
        getline( cin, password );
        if ( password.length() > 20 )
        {
            cout << "The password is too long. The maximum number of characters allowed is 20." << endl;
        }
        else if ( password.length() < 1 )
        {
            cout << "The password is too short. The minimum number of characters allowed is 1." << endl;
        }
    } while ( password.length() < 1 || password.length() > 20 );
    return password;
}

void guess(string password)
{
    //Password 'cracking' happens here.
    int i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, i10, i11, i12, i13, i14, i15, i16, i17, i18, i19, i20;
    char c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13, c14, c15, c16, c17, c18, c19, c20;
    string s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10, s11, s12, s13, s14, s15, s16, s17, s18, s19, s20, ss;
    for ( i1 = 1; i1 < 126; i1++ )
    {
        if ( i1 > 2 )
        {
            c1 = i1;
            s1 = c1;
        }
        for ( i2 = 1; i2 < 126; i2++ )
        {
            if ( i2 > 2 )
            {
            c2 = i2;
            s2 = c2;
            }
            for ( i3 = 1; i3 < 126; i3++ )
            {
                if ( i3 > 2 )
                {
                    c3 = i3;
                    s3 = c3;
                }
                for ( i4 = 1; i4 < 126; i4++ )
                {
                    if ( i4 > 2 )
                    {
                        c4 = i4;
                        s4 = c4;
                    }
                    for ( i5 = 1; i5 < 126; i5++ )
                    {
                        if ( i5 > 2 )
                        {
                            c5 = i5;
                            s5 = c5;
                        }
                        for ( i6 = 1; i6 < 126; i6++ )
                        {
                            if ( i6 > 2 )
                            {
                                c6 = i6;
                                s6 = c6;
                            }
                            for ( i7 = 1; i7 < 126; i7++ )
                            {
                                if ( i7 > 2 )
                                {
                                    c7 = i7;
                                    s7 = c7;
                                }
                                for ( i8 = 1; i8 < 126; i8++ )
                                {
                                    if ( i8 > 2 )
                                    {
                                        c8 = i8;
                                        s8 = c8;
                                    }
                                    for ( i9 = 1; i9 < 126; i9++ )
                                    {
                                        if ( i9 > 2 )
                                        {
                                            c9 = i9;
                                            s9 = c9;
                                        }
                                        for ( i10 = 1; i10 < 126; i10++ )
                                        {
                                            if ( i10 > 2 )
                                            {
                                                c10 = i10;
                                                s10 = c10;
                                            }
                                            for ( i11 = 1; i11 < 126; i11++ )
                                            {
                                                if ( i11 > 2 )
                                                {
                                                    c11 = i11;
                                                    s11 = c11;
                                                }
                                                for ( i12 = 1; i12 < 126; i12++ )
                                                {
                                                    if ( i12 > 2 )
                                                    {
                                                        c12 = i12;
                                                        s12 = c12;
                                                    }
                                                    for ( i13 = 1; i13 < 126; i13++ )
                                                    {
                                                        if ( i13 > 2 )
                                                        {
                                                            c13 = i13;
                                                            s13 = c13;
                                                        }
                                                        for ( i14 = 1; i14 < 126; i14++ )
                                                        {
                                                            if ( i14 > 2 )
                                                            {
                                                                c14 = i14;
                                                                s14 = c14;
                                                            }
                                                            for ( i15 = 1; i15 < 126; i15++ )
                                                            {
                                                                if ( i15 > 2 )
                                                                {
                                                                    c15 = i15;
                                                                    s15 = c15;
                                                                }
                                                                for ( i16 = 1; i16 < 126; i16++ )
                                                                {
                                                                    if ( i16 > 2 )
                                                                    {
                                                                        c16 = i16;
                                                                        s16 = c16;
                                                                    }
                                                                    for ( i17 = 1; i17 < 126; i17++ )
                                                                    {
                                                                        if ( i17 > 2 )
                                                                        {
                                                                            c17 = i17;
                                                                            s17 = c17;
                                                                        }
                                                                        for ( i18 = 1; i18 < 126; i18++ )
                                                                        {
                                                                            if ( i18 > 2 )
                                                                            {
                                                                                c18 = i18;
                                                                                s18 = c18;
                                                                            }
                                                                            for ( i19 = 1; i19 < 126; i19++ )
                                                                            {
                                                                                if ( i19 > 2 )
                                                                                {
                                                                                    c19 = i19;
                                                                                    s19 = c19;
                                                                                }
                                                                                for ( i20 = 1; i20 < 126; i20++ )
                                                                                {
                                                                                    c20 = i20;
                                                                                    s20 = c20;
                                                                                    ss = s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6 + s7 + s8 + s9 + s10 + s11 + s12 + s13 + s14 + s15 + s16 + s17 + s18 + s19 + s20;
                                                                                    if ( ss != password )
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        cout << ss << " : Access denied." << endl;
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    else
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        cout << ss << " : Access granted." << endl;
                                                                                        exit(0);
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    //Type in a password.
    string password = get_password();
    //Trying to get your password.
    guess(password);
}
```

Comment: I think you've gone a little bit overboard with the nested code there... :)

Comment: The words "maintainable" and "readable" come to mind....

Comment: thank god this is just for fun.

Comment: Um... yikes. Have you ever heard of [data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure)?

Comment: People, I'm really new and still learning. I got into C++ like a couple weeks ago. It's obvious the program isn't going to be perfect, it's not like I'm getting paid to do it or something either... If you don't want to, there's no need to answer, just ignore this question. Answering to make fun of me isn't going to help.

Comment: @Aesteras If you are learning, start with less code. Move from simple to complex. Make a simple program that works, then add functionality incrementally.

Comment: Ok, just to clarify: This program works. The only thing is I wonder why in some specific circumstances, it keeps beeping, and if left on its own, eventually crashes after some time. I'm just curious as to what actually is that beeping.
The program itself is not so complicated, it just has a lot  (20) of loops in order to check each one of the possible introduced characters. If you skip to the 20th, you'll see the "exit(0);" that I mention in the description.
Other than that, the program is quite simple, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing out non-printable characters. specifically, your loop generates characters with ASCII-values below 32, which include (among others) the `BEL` character, that will produce a beep when being "printed".

The reason why it keeps beeping after the program terminated, is most likely buffering of your console: your program generates output faster than the console can display it, so the output gets written to a buffer and is printed from there; once your program has finished, the buffer still needs to be printed out.

Comment: Oh, I see. That was very helpful, thanks for your answer!
I would upvote your answer but I don't have reputation...

Comment: By the way, I've made the characters start at 32 and the program now does not beep anymore and neither does it crash if the password is longer. I think the beeping was causing the crashes at the end of the program maybe? Well, It works perfectly now, only it takes a while if the password is 3+ characters long, but it was just for fun anyway. Thanks again! :)

Comment: most likely the crash was caused by some of the unprintable characters, though probably not by the `BEL`